# How to use opencv python with non cuda gpu?

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, tflite, imx8

I want to use Opencv with with gpu support. But I am not having a nvidia gpu in my system. I am having amd raedon gpu in my system. Also I want the python code to run in a edge device like Toradex Apalis IMX.8+ ultimately. So is there a way to compile opencv and  tensorflow tflite to run faster using gpu in those systems?

Comment: i thin kyo uwill have to build it yourself. not sure it will work on python though . take a look to the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d2/dbc/cuda_intro.html)

Comment: sure it'll work with Python. OpenCV can use OpenCL in a lot of functions, if you use `UMat`. it can also use other acceleration paths. depends on the system. -- @Ivan OP specifically said the target system contains no NVIDIA GPU, so CUDA is out of the question.